# Parse SOAP request php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, soap, xml-parsing

I am new to webservices and would like to learn it.
Please let me know the best and easiest way to parse soap request on soap server. My webservice is working fine but I have the following issues:

1. I cannot get values from soap request. I tried DOMDocument as well as simplexml_load_file. But I couldnot get anything. I mean, client is sending soap request, but I cannot parse it in order to process.
2. I cannot test how my function is working on server. I send a request from soap client and whatever I print, var_dump on server doesn't work, I can only see return value or client exception. I need to get request soap into array and process it and save to DB and return response. I tried to print/view/see client request, but failed. I need to see it as array to loop through and save to DB.

Please help.

SOAP Server:

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");

$server = new SoapServer("my.wsdl");

function hello($params){
    $response = array(
        "output1" => "requestOutputOne",
        "output2" => "requestOutputTwo"
    );
    return $response;

}

$server->addFunction('hello');
$server->handle();

?>
```

SOAP Client:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");

    try 
    {            
        $client = new SoapClient("my.wsdl", array('trace' => 1));

        $params = array(
            "input1"=>"requestInputOne",
            "input2"=>"requestInputTwo"
        );

        $response = $client->hello($params);

        header("Content-Type: text/xml");


        echo $client->__getLastResponse();

    } 
    catch (SoapFault $e) {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($e); echo '</pre>';
    }

 ?>

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<input>
<item>
    <key>input1</key>
    <value>requestInputOne</value>
</item>
<item>
    <key>input2</key>
    <value>requestInputTwo</value>
</item>
</input>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: can we see your code please

Comment: @Satya please help if you can. I pasted my code. I am returning simple response array, but I want to process request $params. How can I read that soap request and save to Database

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$response = $client->hello($params);

$p=objectToArray($response);
recurse($p);
}

function objectToArray( $object )
    {
        if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) )
        {
            return $object;
        }
        if( is_object( $object ) )
        {
            $object = get_object_vars( $object );
        }
        return array_map( 'objectToArray', $object );
    }

function recurse ($array)
{
    //statements
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        # code...
        if( is_array( $value ) )
        {   
          recurse( $value );
        }
        else
        {   $v=$value;
            $v=str_replace("&rsquo;",'\'',strip_tags($v));
            $v=str_replace("&ndash;",'-',$v);
            $v=str_replace("&lsquo;",'\'',strip_tags($v));
            $v=str_replace("&ldquo;",'"',strip_tags($v));
            $v=str_replace("&rdquo;",'"',strip_tags($v));
            $v=str_replace("&#8211;",'-',strip_tags($v));
            $v=str_replace("&#8217;",'\'',strip_tags($v));
            $v=str_replace("&#39;",'\'',strip_tags($v));
            $v=str_replace("&nbsp;",'',strip_tags($v));
            $v=html_entity_decode($v);
            $v=str_replace("&",' and ',$v);
        $v = ereg_replace("\r\n", "", $v);
            $v = ereg_replace("\r", "", $v);

            $v = ereg_replace("\t", "", $v);
        $v =  preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $v);
              echo '<'.$key .'>'. trim($v)  .'</'.$key.'>';
        }
  }
```

using this you will have all keys and values available for you to insert in the DB

Comment: sorry this did not work. Please have a look at soap request above. This is what being sent to server. I need to process it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer myself:

```
$xml = $params->item;
$result = array();

foreach ($xml as $item)
{
    $result[$item->key] = $item->value;

}
```

This builds new array containing all key=>value from soap xml. This function is used in SoapServer above to process data sent from Soapclient.